# Есть ли разница в использовании памяти при использовании глобальной const и генератора?

Tags: javascript, память, генераторы

Есть ли разница в потреблении памяти и быстродействии при использовании **глобальной** переменной, хранящей некий немаленький, но статичный список или словарь:

```
const a = [1, 4, .... x]
const b = { a: 123, ... n: 'qwe' }
```

по сравнению с генератором, типа:

```
const a = () => [1, 4, .... x]
const b = { a: 123, ... n: 'qwe' }
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то глобальная переменная сразу выделит себе кусок памяти в куче и будет занимать его всё время жизни программы. В то время, как генератор будет по мере надобности выделять память в куче под эти значения, которые затем будут удаляться сборщиком мусора. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Во-первых, при чём тут python? Во-вторых, в javascript нет понятий «список» или «словарь», а показанный вами код создаёт массивы и объекты

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Внутри генератора у вас снова "глобальная" переменная. Она конечно не глобальная, но будет создана в памяти в момент компиляции кода и будет занимать место до конца работы программы.

Comment: Если написать генератор аккуратно, то будет экономия памяти. Например `def gen(): c = 0; while True: yield c; c += 1` - бесконечный генератор, занимающий мало места.

Comment: Все зависит от того, как эти объекты используются у вас в коде. Все что в глобальной области, то живет вечно, все что создано внутри, условно { ... } то удаляется сборщиком мусора, если ссылок нет

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy,  Код `const a = [1, 4, .... x]` по сути является инструкцией, для выделения памяти и сохранении ссылки на неё в переменной `a`. И эта инструкция будет выполнена когда вызывается. Если она вызвана в глобальном скоупе, то, так как `a` существует всегда и память будет занята всегда. А если инструкция  вызвана внутри функции, то ссылка на область памяти будет уничтожена с выходом из области видимости функции. Следовательно и память будет почищена. К тому же списки и словари по сути своей изменяемые, поэтому вряд ли компилятор станет создавать их в памяти как константы.

Comment: @andreymal при том, что "списки и словари" в python, это то же самое, что и "массивы и объекты" в js. А по большому счёту - это всё объекты.

Comment: @JhwhInri если «списки и словари» действительно чем-то похожи, то вот объекты в javascript работают сильно иначе чем словари в python

Comment: @JhwhInri, вы ошибаетесь. Вот эта часть `[1, 4, .... x]` - литерал. Их создаёт компилятор один раз. Они существуют вечно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если я скажу `a.splise(0)`, то `a` станет равна `[]`. Нет ничего вечного  )

Comment: @SwaD, на литерал ссылается определение функции. Пока вы его не удалите, вы не сможете удалить и литерал.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy про литерал, это я не подумал.. Вы правы. А если избежать использования литерала?
`const a = () => { let res = []; res.push(1);... res.push(x); return res; }`
Хотя, наверное, тут это уже зависит от размера. Неочевидно когда это может иметь практичный смысл.

Comment: @JhwhInri, теперь литерала нет, под него не нужна память. К сожалению, код теперь занимает больше места чем литерал.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, Вы правы. Это не целесообразно. Объем данных всяко меньше, чем те же данные плюс команды и инструкции к этим данным. К тому же это процессорное время на запись в память по одному значению, каждый раз, когда эти данные понадобятся, против только операций чтения.